# Save Bitmap into File and return File having bitmap image

Tags: android

I have a problem to save Bitmaps into files.
My method is like this:

```
private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    File file = new File(bmp + ".png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, bmp + ".png");
        Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + bmp);
    }
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return file;

}
```

It gives me error of file.I am calling this method like this:

```
Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
File file = savebitmap(bitmap);
```

Please help me...

Comment: What is the meaning of this line File file = new File(bmp + ".png");?

Comment: define "error of file" (i.e. post stacktrace)

Comment: @FestusTamakloe I guess he falsely assumes that `bmp.toString()` will return the `name` of the bmp,

Comment: You have to give your file a real name, bmp + ".png" won't work. Please post your error stack also

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I try to make some corrections on your code
I assume that you want to use filename instead of bitmap as parameter

```
 private File savebitmap(String filename) {
      String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      OutputStream outStream = null;

      File file = new File(filename + ".png");
      if (file.exists()) {
         file.delete();
         file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".png");
         Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
      }
      try {
         // make a new bitmap from your file
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getName());

         outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
         outStream.flush();
         outStream.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      Log.e("file", "" + file);
      return file;

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write like this

```
 File file = new File(bmp + ".png");
```

and this line is also wrong

```
file = new File(extStorageDirectory, bmp + ".png");
```

You have to give **string** value and not bitmap.

```
 File file = new File(filename + ".png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
    File file = new File(bmp + ".png");
to
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory,"bmp.png");
like you did nearly the second time.