# how to convert or clip a circular image back to a square image in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have retrieved my profile picture from Facebook and displayed it in the ImageView. But before displaying it I cropped the image to a circular form. The circular image is saved in the sdcard. Now what I want to do is display this image in a square form in another ImageView which is in another activity. So is it possible to change the circular image back to square? If yes please tell me how should I do it. I have cropped the image to circle using the following codes.

```
 Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

 BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bm,  TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);

 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setShader(shader);
 Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);

 c.drawCircle(bm.getWidth()/2, bm.getHeight()/2, bm.getWidth()/2, paint);
 paint.setAntiAlias(true);
 paint.setShadowLayer(10, 10, 5,Color.RED);
 paint.setShadowLayer(40,100 , 100,Color.RED);
 myImageView1.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

Comment: your Bitmap bm is the square one, you can reuse that bitmap unless you are overwriting this variable

Comment: @blackbelt I am cropping the Image to circle and displaying on a ImageView and from there i am saving it in the sdcard. And I need to display the other image in another activity so bm is not gonna work.

Comment: How to save the Bitmap in the sdcard?

Comment: this is how to save your bitmap, you will have to modify slightly de correct answer to your purposes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428975/save-bitmap-into-file-and-return-file-having-bitmap-image