# Saving bitmap to internal/external storage in android studio

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-external-storage, internal-storage

I made an drawing application in android studio. how can I save the drawing in the internal storage and view it afterwards in another activity? I've got some codes in the internet on how to save the bitmap but it won't work and I don't what I've done wrong. I am already stuck in this part.

Here are some of the codes:

```
public onClick(View v){

if(v.getId() == R.id.btnBrush){
.....
}

else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnErase){
.....
}

else if(v.getId() == R.id.ibtnSave){
        //save button clicked
        final Dialog saveDialog = new Dialog(this);
        saveDialog.setTitle("Save");
        saveDialog.setContentView(R.layout.save_form);
        saveDialog.show();



        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.drawFile);
        inputDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        btnSave = (Button) saveDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnCancel = (Button) saveDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                save();
                saveDialog.dismiss();

                Intent intent = new Intent(DrawingPanel.this, Gallery.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

                iView.destroyDrawingCache();


            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}

public void save(){
    Bitmap bitmap = iView.getDrawingCache();

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(inputName.getText().toString() + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        if(fos != null){
            Toast saved = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            saved.show();
        }
        else{
            Toast unsaved = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not save.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            unsaved.show();
        }

        fos.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("save()", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I want to add the date on it as well but I just don't know how to do it. I am really sorry guys. I'm just new in android studio and I am not really good at this that's why I need help cause I really want to learn.

Comment: Did you add permission in 'manifest.xml' ?

Comment: `inputName.getText().toString() `. You should exactly tell what you typed in there.

Comment: `it won't work`. Well you should better tell what exactly does not work. How far flows your code? Any exceptions or errors?

Comment: `if(fos != null)`. That does not tell if something got saved. Better check the return value of bitmap.compress()..

Answer (score 1):

```
public void save(){

    Bitmap bitmap = iView.getDrawingCache();

    try{
    if(bitmap!=null){

        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirr");
        if(!file.isDirectory()){
            file.mkdir();
        }

        file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/dirr",inputName.getText()+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");

        try 
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
            if(bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, fileOutputStream))
            {
                Toast saved = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                saved.show();
            }
            else{
                Toast unsaved = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not save.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                unsaved.show();
            }


        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
             try {
               if (fileOutputStream!= null) {
                 // fileOutputStream.flush();
                  fileOutputStream.close();
               }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
       }

    }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("save()", e.getMessage());
        }   
}
```

And add permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

EDIT: Just cleaned the code a bit, and also you can take a look on similar questions:

[Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

[Save Bitmap into File and return File having bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428975/save-bitmap-into-file-and-return-file-having-bitmap-image)

[How to save a bitmap on internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662258/how-to-save-a-bitmap-on-internal-storage)

Comment: `if(fileOutputStream!= null)`. Wrong. You should check the return value of bitmap.compress.

Comment: @AB, I tried your codes but it has errors with the fileOutputStream in the finally. and it also says that 'finally' without 'try'.

Comment: I still need help on this one. it won't save anything. It just crashes everytime I try to save.

Comment: how can I check the return value of bitmap.compress?

Comment: and it says that file.mkdir() is ignored

Comment: and I'm also having this problem whenever I click the Edititext "GetLabel fail! Do framework orig behavior"