# Uploading image using Dropbox API, Android

Tags: android, file, upload, dropbox

After capturing an image, I'm unsure of how to upload the bitmap as a file.  I get the bitmap this way:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST_CODE){
             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                  final Bitmap image = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
             }
        }
    }
```

Using Dropbox API, a file is uploaded this way:

```
File file = new File("working-draft.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Entry response = mDBApi.putFile("/magnum-opus.txt", inputStream,
                            file.length(), null, null);
Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428975/save-bitmap-into-file-and-return-file-having-bitmap-image

Comment: The `putFile` method takes an `InputStream` so if you can get the data into an `InputStream` directly, you can avoid writing it to a file in between.

Comment: It also takes file.length(), though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it:

- Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`
- Call `Bitmap.compress()` to write the JPEG/PNG bytes to outputstream
- Create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from the byte array you just output
- Use that input stream for your `putFile()` method
- Use the array size for your file length

I would be cautious about memory, though.  It it was me, I'd try to find a way to return the bitmap source in the activity result instead of the actual bitmap.